# How to list two jobs at the same company on resume with a break

Tags: interviewing, resume, human-resources, employment-gaps

I have a problem in listing two jobs at the same company.

I was hired with a contract of 2 years for a project (from April 2014 to April 2016). After that, I did not want to take the first job, so I took few months off (7-8 months). Then the company called me again to start with another project from December 2016 to December 2018 (unfortunately still temporary).
Since my contract will be over in few months, I will be back on the market soon, but this time I would like to find a permanent job.

I am wondering how I could list my last 4 years (in different roles, but not so much). Should I list the gap of 5 months or not?

I could have this option (that shows the gap):

- Business Development Manager, Company A, December 2016-present (2-year contract)
- Marketing Specialist, Company A, April 2014-April 2016 (2-year contract)

I could have this option (no gap, no mentioning temporary contract)

Company A April 2014-present:
- Business Development Manager (2016-present)
- Marketing Specialist (2014-2016)

What do you think? How would you list it? I am afraid they will think they do not want to hire me. And if I put the gap, what should I say?

Comment: April to December is a 5 month gap?

Comment: @maskedman yes, do you think it's not?

Comment: 1. May, 2. June, 3. July, 4. August, 5. September, 6. October, 7. November. That is *at least* 7 months (assuming the gap started on May 1, and ended on November 30), possibly more.

Comment: You are right. They are not 5, but 8. I wrongly calculated. This make the situation worse?

Answer (score 5):

I think that either option is fine (as they are both truthful), so perhaps you should chose the one you feel more comfortable with, or the one that better adapts to your specific circumstances.

I also think that **such employment gap is something you should not worry much** (so you could show the gap just to be crystal clear with the recruiters). Everybody is prone to be "caught between jobs" in any moment. As long as your gaps are not frequent or really extended everything should be ok.

In any case, be **prepared to explain such gap if prompted about it during any interview** that might come. Not necessarily they will ask about it, but if they do just explain your reasons and they should understand.

If on doubt, I would suggest you add the dates to show the gap, just to be completely unambiguous and clear with your application.

Comment: Would you mention that were both fixed term contract?

Comment: @Rudin01877 maybe its not absolutely necessary, as it could take space for other more relevant highlights you could mention. But leaving it surely isnt something that could probably harm you

Comment: I'm surprised at your answer. Maybe I'm reading the question differently than you. I don't really see the second option as truthful, since it leaves the impression that the employment was continuous (to quote the question, from "April 2014 - present").

Comment: @dwizum As stated in my answer, it would be better to be crystal clear and specify the start and end dates. However, given that this was in the same company, leaving those details out (but answering with the truth if prompted) wouldn't be untruthful. As long as OP does not deny them, and answers with the truth if asked about it.

Comment: Thank you for making the edit, I think it helps clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the second option, simply because it takes up less space by not requiring you to list the company name twice.  Most hiring managers won't care about the gap, especially since the same company took you back.  This implies that whatever the reason for the gap, it had nothing to do with your performance.  This is information that will turn up in background checks, regardless of whether or not you explicitly state it on your resume, so it really doesn't matter as long as you don't lie.

Comment: and would you list the years or also the month? E.g: 1) Company A April 2014-present and then 2014-2016 Role A, 2016-present Role B                or 2) Company A April 2014-present and then April 2014-April 2016 Role A, Dec 2016- present Role B

Answer (score 1):

Your second option, showing "April 2014-present" next to the company name, and listing the positions only with years (not months) doesn't leave the impression that there was a gap. While an 8 month gap may not be a critical issue with a resume, **feeling like you were misled about a gap certainly is a critical issue.**

To put it a different way: As a hiring manager, if I saw:

> Company A April 2014-present

on a resume, I would assume you had worked there continuously from April 2014 until the present date. **A resume is a sales tool** - you want to present yourself in a way that makes you attractive to the employer, but you never want to put yourself in a position where you may be *misleading* an employer.

In other words: while you don't want to *emphasize* the gap, you don't want to act like it didn't happen, either. **This makes the first option you presented the most attractive** - you're showing the *correct* employment record, but you're not emphasizing the "issue" of the gap.

You'll likely be asked about the gap in an interview, so have a good answer ready.

Comment: So you would list the company twice basically, right? Like this:
Business Development Manager, Company A, December 2016-present (2-year contract)
Marketing Specialist, Company A, April 2014-April 2016 (2-year contract) I hope being re-enrolled in the same company is a plus. Plus the company is very well known world wide. So I can explain the gap as it is : didn't want any job and the old company promised me a new contract (So I was not interested in any job).

Comment: It's hard to be that specific because I think it depends a bit on the overall look and feel of your resume. I don't know if it makes sense, space-wise, to put the same company name twice - maybe just list the name once, and each position with the timeframes (including months) as appropriate, mentioning that each was a 2 year contract. Overall, my point was that I think you need to be careful that you're not "covering up" or "hiding" the gap by writing as if you were continuously employed, because you weren't.